# How to form a matrix of two datasets in R?

Tags: r

If I sample

```
 a<-rgamma(100, 4, 10)
 b<-rnorm(100, 2, 6)
```

I want to sample a data matrix `M` and each entry `M(i,j)~Normal(a[i], b[j]`. For example,

```
 M(1,1)<-rnorm(1, a[1], b[1])
```

But I do not know how to form this matrix? Like use for loop?

Comment: You need to reformulate your question or think more carefully about the problem. For instance, `theta[1, 2]` in your matrix must be a *single* number. In your code, you are assigning *two* numbers to it: `c(a[j], b[j])`. Also, al 100 by 100 matrix has 10000 entries, whereas your a and b vectors only have 100 entries each. They just don't match, unless you're willing to repeat. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with a 5x5 matrix. You can change the first line to make your matrix bigger.

Note that I inverted the order of `a` and `b` because it is impossible to draw from a normal distribution with negative standard deviation, and the `b` vector includes negative values.

```
N <- 5
a <- rgamma(N, 4, 10)
b <- rnorm(N, 2, 6)
M <- matrix(ncol=N, nrow=N)
for (i in 1:N) {
  for (j in 1:N) {
    M[i, j] <- rnorm(1, mean=b[j], sd=sqrt(a[i]))
  }
}
M
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
#> [1,] 4.525953 14.10435 11.83800 1.922218 -3.360052
#> [2,] 4.504492 14.01858 11.62823 2.056981 -3.023448
#> [3,] 4.591491 14.23959 12.06540 2.054371 -3.187501
#> [4,] 3.819474 14.16737 11.63790 2.252287 -3.411978
#> [5,] 4.900445 13.72671 12.13339 2.494865 -3.264389
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `rnorm(1, b[j], sqrt(a[i[))`? Beacuse if `M(i,j)~N(b[j], a[i])`, the sd is square roof of a[i].

Comment: You did not specify this in your original question, but yes, if `a` is a variance then you need to take the square root. I edited my answer to show you how.